# Set of fractal needed

Tags: fractals, visualization

I am preparing for some cognitive study. For one of the experiment I need to produce a set of fractal pictures (10-30 pictures). For study consistence these fractals should belong to one class (from mathematical point of view), Should share some common features, but be visually distinguishable. So, in other words, I am searching for fractals, which are like dogs types: looks very different, but everybody absolutely sure, that they belong to one species.

**Could you give me advice which fractals I may try?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Julia set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set) (which depends on a complex constant) and [Newton fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal) (which depends on a polynomial) immediately come to mind.

I wonder what kind of study are you doing.

Comment: Thank You!!! Julia set looks what I need. Concerning study - it is hard to explain. I just need a set of pictures not from real life to teach observer some their sequence. After teaching I will demonstrate them in "unusual order". I am interested on some fMRI signal for "unexpected" events.